# MATLAB install fails: Error extracting tbx.signal.common!

Tags: fedora, software-installation, matlab

I'm trying to run MATLAB R2008b student on my Fedora Linux machine, but get the following after I run `/.install`:

```
Error extracting tbx.signal.common!!!
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think that package is broken (the zip file),

During installation of Matlab 2012a, I found the `Computer Vision` package fails to install due to similar error message, so I digged a bit, and finally find that zip file is empty.

Just grab a new media.

P.S You have write permission to the installation folder right?

Comment: Do you have enough free space?

Comment: @vonbrand yes, more than 20g